# Wine not working for Linux Mint 18 Sarah. Trying to run Game Maker Studio, with no luck

Tags: linux-mint, wine, programming

I'm using **Linux Mint 18 Sarah MATE 32 bit** and I'm trying to download Game Maker Studio off of **Wine 1.6.2**. It was named **"GMStudio-Installer-1.4.1763.exe"**.

At first the installation process went perfectly, but Game Maker Studio didn't work.

Then Wine wasn't working anymore. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled Wine. Then I tried it *again* but it said (exactly):

> Installation failed.
>
> This software requires Windows Framework 3.5.* or higher
>
> No version of Windows Framework is installed.
>
> Please update your computer at
> [https://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/).

Now I can't install *anything* off of Wine anymore.
I looked up what to do on [WineHQ](http://winehq.org), but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to this site! I appreciate your issue is solved. Do note, however, that there's little value on editing the question title once you've accepted an answer. Have you taken the [Welcome Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)? If not, it is encouraged. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command as root:

```
rm -r /home/[enter your username here]/.wine
```

This will remove the entire Wine system.

Now reinstall Wine. This will depend on your package manager.

Finally, rebuild Wine by running `winecfg` as your normal user.

Comment: It said `rm: cannot remove 'home/[EXPLICIT CONTENT]/.wine': No such file in directory`

Comment: @CrimzicZ Then just try reinstalling Wine (and maybe Mono, it's the mono-devel package), then run winecfg to reset it.

Comment: there is no such thing as "mono-devel package" when I looked up Wine in the Software Manager... -_-

Comment: @CrimzicZ Really? Have you tried installing "mono-devel" through the terminal? Open it up and type in "sudo apt-get install mono-devel". You should still try the above steps anyway.

Comment: wait doing `winecfg` really helped thx prob dont need help now but keep on here just in case ;)

Comment: @CrimzicZ No problem :). You might want to accept this answer (click the checkmark underneath the down arrow), but you may have to wait 2 days to do that.

Comment: wait it says when i downloaded it "no file found". Can u help plz?

Comment: @CrimzicZ Run `cd ~/Downloads` in a terminal, then `wine [the name of the file].exe`